# Android Studio - ListView refresh isn't working after insert data in database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

Basicly I use a method to return a list (with all the contacts in the database) that will ovewrite a list that is the base list to my listview. After that "overwriting" I try to refresh the list using `((BaseAdapter)EmergenciaFragment.lvContatosEmergencia.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();`
 but nothing happens. I only can refresh the listView finishing the activity and oppening it again.

I use this method to return a List with all the contacts in the database:

```
public List<Contato> buscaContatos(int tipo) {
    List<Contato> listContatos = new ArrayList<>();

    String table = Utility.getTableName(tipo);

    Cursor cursor = connection.query(table, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    Log.d("Log","List size: " + cursor.getCount());

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        do {
            listContatos.add(new Contato(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(2), tipo));
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    cursor.close();
    return listContatos;
}
```

And I try to use this method to refresh de listView

```
public static void refreshListView() {

    EmergenciaFragment.contatos = MainActivity.dbController.buscaContatos(Contato.EMERGENCIA);
    ((BaseAdapter)EmergenciaFragment.lvContatosEmergencia.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

This method is called on the activity that contains the fragment that contains the listview

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    EmergenciaFragment.refreshListView();

}
```

The list EmergenciaFragment.contatos is the base list to the listView;

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Why do you need static method and static variable in here? You can do all work in your EmergenciaFragment.

Comment: Why should I create a non-static method if it can be static?

Comment: Static variables will take your memory. And more importantly, static method will not be able to override. It takes a lot of flexibility out from your design. You can find for refer with @tetsuo's answer in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods

Comment: But did you understand my problem? I ovewrite the list of the listview with a method that return all the objects of the database and call notifyDataSetChanged(), but nothing happens.

Comment: Static method can cause concurrency bugs and/or bottlenecks. Some problems are hard to find. Maybe you refresh the listview before a new list is updated. I need to debug to see what is your problem.